# Tomcat not logging to file

Tags: java, tomcat

Hi wrote my own little Logger class to write log output into files, the class looks like this:

```
public class Logger {
    private String prefix;
    private String pathToLogFiles = "/tmp/sos/logs/";
    private String infoLog;
    private String errorLog;
    private boolean doLogtoFile;

    public Logger(String prefix, Class classname, boolean logToFile) {
        this.prefix = "[" + prefix + "]";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        Date now = new Date();
        this.infoLog = this.pathToLogFiles + "info_" + sdf.format(now) + ".log";
        this.errorLog = this.pathToLogFiles + "error_" + sdf.format(now) + ".log";
        this.doLogtoFile = logToFile;
        System.out.println("Will log to: " + this.infoLog + " and " + this.errorLog);
    }

    public void info(String message) {
        String logmessage = prefix + " INFO " + message;
        if( this.doLogtoFile ) {
            try {
                Files.write(Paths.get(infoLog), logmessage.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(prefix + message);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(prefix + message);
        }
    }

    public void error(String message) {
        String logmessage = prefix + " ERROR " + message;
        if( this.doLogtoFile ) {
            try {
                Files.write(Paths.get(errorLog), logmessage.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(prefix + message);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(prefix + message);
        }
    }
}
```

Permissions of the directory and subdirectories are all set up correctly and owned by the tomcat user. However I don't receive any logoutput, nor are the log files even created.

Could anyone see what could be going wrong?

Strangely enough I am not getting any Exception

Many thanks for any help

Comment: a) don't invent your own logging framework. b) does the System.out.println part work?

Comment: Are you getting any errors, have you tried attaching debugger?
I would suggest using dedicated library for this, for example SLF4J + Logback combination, currently it seems you try to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Where would I be able to see the System.out logs when Tomcat is running the code? I know it's an unpopular opinion but I like to use my own Loggers instead of using libraries for that.

Comment: see what's happening at catalina.out - there might be exceptions from your logger